# Do we have to take a second subgroup to use the property of $G$? - Show that the groups are nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotence

Let $G$ be a finite group with the following property:

for each two of its subgroups $X,Y\subseteq G$ it holds either $X\cap Y=1$ or $X\subseteq Y$ or $Y\subseteq X$.

I want to show the following:

1. If $H\leq G$ then either $|H|$ is a power of a prime or $|H|$ and $|G:H|$ are co-prime.
2. If $1<N\trianglelefteq G$, then $G/N$ is nilpotent.
3. If $N\trianglelefteq G$ and$N\neq G$, then $N$ is nilpotent.

$$$$

As for 2. :

So that $G/N$ is nilpotent we have to find a series of normal subgroups
$$1\leq N_1\leq N_2\leq \dots \leq N_k=G/N$$
so that $N_{i+1}/N_i\subseteq Z((G/N)/N_i)$.

We have that $1<N\trianglelefteq G$.

Do we have to use the correspondence theorem to find he corresponding series for $G/N$ ?

But how can we show that quotient group belongs to the center?

But when we take the corresponding series, using the correspondence theorem, do we not get $1\leq G/N$ ?

That means that we have to check if $G/N\subseteq Z(G/N)$, or not?

Comment: For 2 I suppose you can use that the subgroups of $G/N$ are linearly ordered: if $X/N$ and $Y/N$ are subgroups, then $X\cap Y=\{1\}$ cannot happen, so either $X\subseteq Y$ or $Y\subseteq X$.

Comment: Do we suppose that $X/N$ and $Y/N$ are subgroups of $G/N$, only when $X$ and $Y$ are subgroups of $G$ ? @egreg

Comment: Of course we do!

Comment: Why can $X\cap Y=\{1\}$ not happen? @egreg

Comment: Because $X$ and $Y$ are subgroups containing $N$.

Comment: Ah ok... So, having that either $X\subseteq Y$ or $Y\subseteq X$, do we have then also that $X/N\subseteq Y/N$ or $Y/N\subseteq X/N$ ? But how can we conclude that $G/N$ is nilpotent? @egreg

Comment: This is *basic* knowledge in group theory. You can't be talking about nilpotent groups without knowing the structure of subgroups of a quotient group.

Comment: Do we have to show that $1\leq X/N\leq Y/N\leq G/N$ or $1\leq Y/N\leq X/N\leq G/N$ satisfy the conditions that I mentionned in my initial post to show that $G/N$ is nilpotent? @egreg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with 1. Suppose that $|H|$ and $|G:H|$ are not coprime, so there is a prime $p$ dividing both. Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(H)$. Then there exists $Q \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$ with $P < Q$, and the containment is strict because $p$ divides $|G:H|$. So $Q \cap H = P$, which is not equal to $Q$ and not equal to $1$. So $Q \cap H = H$ and hence $H=P$.

Comment: We have that the order of $P$ and $Q$ is a power of $p$, but not the same power, right? I haven't really understood why the containment is strict. Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Also how do we know that there is also a $Q\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$ ?

Comment: This is all comes directly  from Sylow's Theorem.

Comment: Ah... I misunderstood... I thought you said $P,Q\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$. We have that $p$ divides $|H|$ so, there is $P\in \text{Syl}_p(H)$, from the first of the Sylow's Theorems. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, by Lagrange's Theorem $p$ divides also $|G|$, so there is $Q\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$. Since $p$ divides also $[G:H]$, we have that $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, or not? But from which of the Sylow's Theorems do we get that the containment is strict, $P<Q$ ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the fact that $p$ divides $|G:H|$ implies that $|Q|>|P|$.

Comment: We have that $|H|=p^na$ and $|G|=p^mb$, since $p$ divides $[G:H]$, where $p\not\mid a,b$ and $a<b$, that's why $p^n=|P|<|Q|=p^m$, right?

Comment: Why does it hold that $P\cap H=Q$ ? I got stuck right now... We have that $P<Q$ and $P\subseteq H$. Would it mean that $P\cap H=P$ ?

Comment: Oh dear I am sorry. I got my $P$s and $Q$s mixed up. I hope it is right now. (There is an old saying "Mind your $P$s and $Q$s". I am not sure exactly what it means, but I clearly failed to observe it!)

Comment: We have that $P\leq H$ and $P<Q$. I still haven't understood why $Q\cap H=P$. Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: No you should prove it yourself.

Comment: Since $|H|=p^na, p\not\mid a$ and $|Q|=p^m$, where $n<m$, we have that the intersection of these two groups must be a $p$-group, and especially a group of order $p^n$, which is $P$. Is this the right justification why $Q\cap H=P$ ?

Comment: Or is there an other reason?

Comment: We have three cases for the two subgroups of $G$, the $H$ and $Q$. Either $Q\cap H=1$ or $Q\subseteq H$ or $H\subseteq Q$. We have that $Q\cap H=P$. $$$$ If $Q\cap H=1$, that would mean that $P=1$. This cannot be true, since $|P|=p^n$, right? $$$$ If $Q\subseteq H$, then we would have $P=Q\cap H=Q$. But since $P<Q$, that cannot be true. $$$$ Therefore, it must be $H\subseteq Q$, and so $P=Q\cap H=H$. Therefore, $|H|=|P|=p^n$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!! :-)